# Set of continuously differentiable function subset of another one

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function. For $k, n \in \mathbb N$, we can define the set $S_{k,n}$ as:

$\{ x \in [0,1]: $ for any $y \in [x - \frac{1}{k}, x + \frac{1}{k}] \cap [0,1]$ it holds $|f(x) - f(y) | \leq \frac{1}{n}|x-y|\}$

How can I show that $S_{k,n} \subset S_{k+1, n}$ and that $S_{k, n+1} \subset S_{k,n}$ for every $k,n \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write down the definition of the two sets, in particular, what it means for $x$ to be in them. You prove that $A\subseteq B$ by showing that if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$.

For example:

Let's prove $S_{k,n}\subseteq S_{k+1,n}$

**What we know**:

If $x\in S_{k,n}$, then we know that for all $y \in \left[x - \frac{1}{k}, x + \frac{1}{k}\right]$, we have $|f(x) - f(y) | \leq \frac{1}{n}|x-y|$

**What we need to prove**:

We need to prove that $x\in S_{k+1, n}$. This is true if and only if, for all $y\in\left[x-\frac{1}{k+1}, x+\frac1{k+1}\right]$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\frac1n|x-y|$.

As usual, when you need to prove something for all $y$, your proof should start with:

> Let $y\in \dots$

and conclude with

> Therefore, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\dots$.

Your next step is to try and construct this proof. Good luck, and if you get stuck, let us know!